# Bounty for self answered question

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have this [question from a user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70736/trouble-connecting-to-share-from-ubuntu-11-10-to-windows) that I was trying to help.

It was taking a bit of time to troubleshot everything so I offered a bounty for it.

After that I could pin point the problem and answer it, user marked it correct.

What happens to the bounty in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What bounty? I don't see a bounty.

Perhaps a nice moderator refunded it.

Comment: no clear if it was you but **thx!** :D